# Angular universal is rendering home page html in page source for every pages

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular5, angular-universal

I've multiple components in my angular universal project. when I route to other components from the home component, I'm only getting the content for the home component in the page source.  It's not getting updated by the routed component.

I've checked whether every components are rendering in server side by console.log in server side, but it's only loading the home page, other components are not getting rendered in server side.

I'm using **npm run build:ssr** for the build and **npm run serve:ssr** for serving on the server side.

There are no errors while running the above commands in the cmd or browser console as well.

Can anybody please help! I'm stuck at this problem for about a week now.

Please let me know if you guys need any other information about the project.

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^1.4.8",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.7.7",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "nouislider": "^11.0.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "cpy-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

**Server.ts**

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import 'localstorage-polyfill';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

// jay
const domino = require('domino');
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
// jay

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**app.server.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ServerModule} from '@angular/platform-server';
import {ModuleMapLoaderModule} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import {AppModule} from './app.module';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // The AppServerModule should import your AppModule followed
    // by the ServerModule from @angular/platform-server.
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule // <-- *Important* to have lazy-loaded routes work
  ],
  // Since the bootstrapped component is not inherited from your
  // imported AppModule, it needs to be repeated here.
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
// Other modules also imported here deleting that for saving space
import { routingComponents, AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    // Imported other components here

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'universal-cli' }),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ModalModule,
    NguCarouselModule
  ],
  providers: [
    // added providers here
  ],
  entryComponents: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "universal-cli"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/browser",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
       "styles.css",
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ssr",
      "platform": "server",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist/server",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.server.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: If you navigate to another url directly in the adresse bar, do you get the correct source code when pressing ctrl+U?

Comment: and that's when you directly using port 4000?

Comment: No I just want to make sure that you are testing correctly. I've seen questions where users where not testing the right thing, or expected the page's source to change while navigating client-side instead of typing the url directly. If you go to `http://yourserver:4000` and press Ctrl+U, you should see some content in `app-root` tag if it's working. And you should see different content in `app-root` if you go to `http://yourserver:4000/someroute` too.

Comment: Thank you @David for the detailed explanation. I've tested that as same as you've mentioned. In http://yourserver:4000 and press Ctrl+U I'm getting the content inside the app-root but when I go to http://yourserver:4000/someroute and press Ctrl+U the content inside app-root is what I got for http://yourserver:4000 and press Ctrl+U, it's not getting updated. I've also updated the title with respect to the page, that's also not getting updated with pages.

Comment: Ok. Your `server.ts` seems correct to me. And you don't get any error in the console server side? Are the other routes you are testing with lazy loaded routes? . Maybe add some console logs in some of your components to see if they are called server side.  And can you also post your app.model.server.ts, your main.server.ts and your .angular-cli.json if using angular-cli

Comment: @David posted other files as you mentioned.

Comment: It all seems correct to me... maybe angular's routing is not triggered somehow. Try adding some console log in your components and router events and see if they are triggered server side. Sorry, I don't have any otehr idea

Comment: @David thank you so much for your valuable inputs :)

Comment: @David As you told I've tried console.log in each component, but it's only consoling for homepage. Do you know what might be the issue? Thanks for sharing this approach

Comment: Not really. Can you show your routing file? And also, can you confirm that you don't have any proxy before nodejs (e.g. nginx/apache/...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the URL structure. 
We've used **HashLocationStrategy** https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/ by adding # in the URL for avoiding 404-page error while refreshing the angular page in the server.

When we've removed the HashLocationStrategy from the application, it's working fine.

@david: Thanks for your support.

Comment: Spent whole in resolving this. that for the answer

Comment: @Alwin Richard we facing also this bug but we not using HashLocationStrategy in project

Comment: @rajpootrehan did you manage to fix it ? I'm not using # strategy and  I'm struggling with the same stuff. I have set up angular universal and I can see same behavior. Only getting home page html from server and it is not updated as change routes

Comment: This issue occurs on auth related pages. If you are logged in and refresh the page then it will show home page content first and after auth is validated it will redirect through route automatically.